# How to make an article disapper in django app

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I 'm new in web development and I started with django 
My question 
if I have article in my blog and a I like to make it disapper after a specific time or date

Delete the full field of the article from the database after a specific time

Comment: Maybe you can write a script and execute it every day with crontab (or windows solution).
The script can delete definitiely the data or set a boolean to true (is_expired).

Answer (score 0):

You can use task queue software:

[django-background-tasks](https://pypi.org/project/django-background-tasks/) is the easiest to setup and good for simple tasks.

Otherwise you could look into [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) or [Redis Queue](http://python-rq.org/) as options with more features, but harder to set up.

Comment: instructions for settings up django-background-tasks here: http://django-background-tasks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Is there any tutorials or videos explain this topic